# How to map over only the Some() values in an iterator?

Tags: rust

Both of the following work (in 2 invocations), but they feel too verbose.

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![Some(0), Some(1), None, Some(2)];
    assert_eq!(
        vec![0,2,4],
        v.iter()
            .filter(|x| x.is_some())
            .map(|x| x.unwrap() * 2)
            .collect::<Vec<u8>>());
    assert_eq!(
        vec![0,2,4],
        v.iter()
            .filter_map(|x| *x)
            .map(|x| x*2)
            .collect::<Vec<u8>>());
}
```

filter_map is *close* to what I want:

> [filter_map] removes the Option layer automatically. If your
> mapping is already returning an Option and you want to skip over
> Nones, then filter_map is much, much nicer to use.

[doc.rust-lang.org](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map)

But it doesn't unwrap the value in the closure because it expects an Option to be returned.

**Is there a way to both filter on only the Some values, and map over those values with a single invocation?**
Such as:

```rust
// Fake, does not work
fn main() {
    let v = vec![Some(0), Some(1), None, Some(2)];
    assert_eq!(
        vec![0,2,4],
        v.iter()
            .map_only_some(|x| x * 2)
            .collect::<Vec<u8>>());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured it out,  and Iterator's next always returns an Option, so you just have to flatten it:

```rust
// Since v.iter().next() is Some(Some(0)), the following works
    assert_eq!(
        vec![0,2,4],
        v.iter()
            .flatten()
            .map(|x| x * 2)
            .collect::<Vec<u8>>());
```

It's not in a single invocation, but it's much much cleaner and, I think, idiomatic.

Comment: Note that this is sticky equivalent to `.filter_map(|x| *x)` just shorter

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to both filter on only the Some values, and map over those values with a single invocation?

You already use it `filter_map()`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![Some(0), Some(1), None, Some(2)];
    assert_eq!(
        vec![0, 2, 4],
        v.iter()
            .filter_map(|x| x.map(|x| x * 2))
            .collect::<Vec<u8>>()
    );
}
```